# Can you connect to GCE via gcutil using Chrome Secure SSH?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to connect to GCE VM instances using Chrome's Secure SSH? If so, how are you all accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here's how to do this:

1. Install the [Chrome SSH extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo), if you haven't already.
2. [Add your SSH key](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/console#sshkeys) to the project.
3. Configure the new connection in Chrome SSH:

   a. Open the extension. You can find it if you open the URL `chrome://apps` if it's not already visible when you open the browser or open a new tab. Or you can also visit its URL in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) and click on the "launch" button.

   b. Find the IP address of your instance via [`gcutil getinstance`](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances#checkmachinestatus) or by looking at your instance on the [Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/console).

   c. Click on the "Import" link, select the two files:

   - `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`
   - `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub`
4. Click on "Connect".